# EGR was deleted. Is this the EGR line?

Tags: emissions, mustang, egr

Someone who owned my 1986 3.8l Mustang before me decided to delete the EGR system. I'm attempting to get this car to pass emissions so I want to reinstall the EGR system. However I want to make sure I'm looking at the correct pieces (and the previous owners didn't do any more damage) before I buy the 85$ EGR setup and attempt to undo their handiwork.

[image: egr valve]
I believe the EGR belongs above the valve cover, and they replaced it with a metal plate in the place of the gasket. The electrical connector that clearly goes to the EGR can be found nearby.

[image: egr line]

Is this open end the line that goes into the EGR? Are these other two lines routed correctly? Am I missing anything else for the EGR to function properly?

I've searched for diagrams for weeks and can't find one for this old engine. I'm hoping someone who's got one can go check under their hood real quick to confirm what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

That could be the line that controls the vacuum unit on the egr, but it depends on if that is the type of egr fitted. If the egr was electrical then that line could be for the distributor, cruise control etc.

Then you need the pipe from the exhaust to the egr and the connection to the inlet manifold.

Comment: The EGR valve is vacuum operated. There is no pipe (or any place where a pipe could go) coming off of the exhaust manifold that I can see, and the valve connects to the intake manifold via the back where it bolts on. There is typically one hole on the back of an EGR valve however this one has two leading me to wonder if the gas is recirculated directly up through the intake manifold, into the EGR right next to where it comes back out.

Comment: As egr is short for Exhaust Gas Recirculation it has to come from somewhere, and, no, it is not blown back into the inlet manifold from the cylinders...